# unable to run javascript code in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I've created a file in visual studio code with the following line:

console.log("Hello World");

I get the following error:

"[Running] node "c:\Users\boyce\Documents\javascript visual studio code\scratchpad-1.js"
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I've also tried running by opening Chrome, but I get error in that application: local host refused cannot connect.

Comment: you need to have node installed. And if you want to use the browser, you'll have to run the code in the browser's dev console

Comment: If you want to use "node" as a command, you also need to make sure to add it as a path variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser runs the JS code because it compiles your code using V8 JavaScript engine. If you want to run your JS codes outside of your browser you need have Node.js installed which uses the same engine on the server side.